# Angular.js - Redirection is cleaning my $scope(?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, frontend, mean-stack

I have an `$ngController` that is being used in two views. The first view has an `<table>` with `ng-repeat` that lists all my data from the db.

I get the selected object form the table by using `get($index)` and set it to a `$scope` variable.

The problem is that when i cannot use this same `$scope` variable on the other view, because its value is `undefined`. Both views share the same `ng-controller`.

**My Question is: is the redirection cleaning my $scope? Is there any way i can share this data between pages since my application isn't single page?**

Things i tried:

- 1 - Share data through a factory
- 2 - Using `$rootScope`

**First View - Table with ng-repeat**

```
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>CNPJ</th>
            <th>Razão Social</th>
            <th>Ações</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="company in companies | filter:{companyName:searchString}">
            <td> {{ company.cnpj }}</td>
            <td> {{ company.companyName }}</td>
            <td>
              <a href="/admin/view-company" ng-click="setCompanyFromTable($index)" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" role="button">Visualizar</a>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Editar</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Deletar</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module("distCad").controller("adminCtlr", function($scope, $http, config, $window, $cacheFactory){
$scope.searchTerm = null;
$scope.hideSearcAlert = true;
$scope.companies = [];

$scope.cache = $cacheFactory('companyCache');

$scope.expireLogin = function(){
  localStorage.removeItem("type");
  $window.location.href = "/";
}

$scope.getResults = function(){
  $scope.searchTerm = true;
  $http.get("/api/companies").then(
    function successCallback(response){
        $scope.companies = response.data;
    },
    function errorCallback(response){
      console.log("aaaa" + response);
    }
  );
}

$scope.getCompany = function(){
   return $scope.cache.get("company");
}

$scope.setCompanyFromTable = function(index){
  $scope.cache.put("company", $scope.companies[index]);
}
```

});

**Destination View - Part where i am testing**

```
  <div class="container" ng-init="getCompany()">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2>Dados da empresa {{cache.get("company").companyName}}</h2>
```

Comment: A factory should work

Comment: already tried, but had no success.

Comment: AngularJS is a single page application framework. To switch from one view to another, you should use `$route` instead of `<a href>`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: While factory and service is a singleton initiated once per app run controllers can be created multiple times and each instance will be a "clean" one, you really need a service/factory to two-way data binding between controller - here is a link to example of two-way data binding http://plnkr.co/edit/pt2xwlYqvY3r840tHJ92?p=preview

Comment: unfortunately, you haven't provided enough information to adequately understand the **full** picture of what's going on.  You have provided a part of a view, with a link to a new page, and then a part of the new page, but you haven't described what is responding to that link.  One can make a *guess* that it might be a server route that is rendering a new HTML document, but that would only be a guess, based on the symptoms you are describing.  If that is the case, your approach won't work, and you don't have a lot of other options, aside from `$localStorage`.